# Can Shiny append to an existing Excel workbook?

Tags: r, excel, shiny, append

Use case: a multi-sheet Excel workbook exists, with content that cannot be handled in R, so uploading the entire workbook and re-writing it with new content is not an option.
The `write.xlsx2` function of the xlsx library can append a new sheet to an existing workbook from an R session, but I have not been able to get Shiny to do the same thing.

Here is an example Shiny app intended to read a sheet from an existing Excel workbook, change the data, and write a new sheet back to the same Excel workbook without disturbing the existing sheet in the workbook. The test_excel workbook I used contained a 3 x 3 matrix of random numbers, with column headings, in a sheet called "Test_data". The example code below is based on an example from another StackOverflow query, but modified to fit my specific use case. The answer to the other query was to use downloadHandler(), which I am using, but it overwrites the existing Excel workbook instead of appending to it. How do I modify the script so that it appends to the existing workbook?

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)
library(readxl)

ui <- fluidPage(   
    titlePanel("Writer App"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(fileInput("file","Read File Here", accept = ".xlsx"),
            downloadButton('download1',"Save to Excel")
        ),
        mainPanel(tableOutput("table1"))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
        observeEvent(eventExpr  = input$file,{
            data <- read_xlsx(input$file$datapath,sheet = "Test_data")
            div_mtx <- data/5

            output$table1 <- renderTable({    
                div_mtx
            }) # end of renderDataTable
    
            output$download1 <- downloadHandler(filename = input$file$name,
                content = function(file) {
                write.xlsx2(div_mtx,file,sheetName="div_mtx",row.names=FALSE,append=TRUE)
            }) # end of downloadHandler
        }) # end of observeEvent
} # end of server

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to define a function in an R script file, and source that file from within the Shiny app server code, then invoke the function to append a data object from the server environment as a new worksheet in the local Excel workbook.
The R script file is saved in a directory called resources within the folder that contains the app.R file, and consists of the following code:

```r
library(rJava)
library(xlsx)

write_data <- function(x, y, z) {
  # x is local data object, y is name of Excel workbook to modify, 
  # z is sheetName in workbook
  write.xlsx2(x, y, sheetName=z, col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, 
              append=TRUE, showNA=FALSE)
  }
```

The app.R script contains the following:

```r
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)
library(readxl)
ui <- fluidPage(   
    titlePanel("Writer App"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("file","Load File to Modify", accept = ".xlsx"),
            textOutput("filename1"),
            actionButton("save","Click to Save")
        ),
        mainPanel(tableOutput("table1"))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

        observeEvent(eventExpr  = input$file,{
            # Save input file name as variable available to global 
            # environment - note double arrow * <<- *
            input_workbook <<- input$file$name
            output$filename1 <- renderText({paste0(
                       "The file to modify is ", input_workbook)})
            # Read data from input Excel workbook, sheet named "Test_data"
            data <- read_xlsx(input$file$datapath, sheet = "Test_data")
            div_mtx <- data/5

            # Use renderTable() to display changed data to Shiny browser 
            # window
            output$table1 <- renderTable({div_mtx})
            
            # Load the source code for the write_data function and invoke 
            # that function with the changed data
            source("./resources/functions.R")
            write_data(div_mtx, input_workbook, "div_mtx")
        }) # end of observeEvent 1
} # end of server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```